# Make c++ macro2 containt quoted body of macro1

Tags: c++, gcc, c-preprocessor, qmake

I'm trying to make some kind of a simple system that calculates the number of builds, including this info in .rc file (for windows) and met the problem. Here it is:

```
#define QUOTE(s) #s
#define A       0,0,0,1
#define A_STR   QUOTE(A)
```

Expanding of A_STR: `"A"` but not `"0,0,0,1"` as I expected.

Well, I need `A_STR` to be a string representation of `A` (that's what `windres` expects to see in .rc file), but I can't find the way to do this.

I've already tried smth like `#define A_STR #A` but it simply expands to `#0,0,0,1`.

I also tried using qmake like this: `DEFINES *= A_STR="<here-is-how-I-get-version>"` but `gcc` gets it without quotes and I've got the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a C preprocessor macro is expanded, its parameters are expanded to their literal arguments, so `s` would be expanded to `A` when your `QUOTE(s)` taking argument `A` is expanded. Normally, after this expansion is complete, the expanded text is then scanned *again* to expand any macros embedded therein, so this would cause the `A` to expand to `0,0,0,1`. However, when the stringification operator `#` is used to stringify the following text, that stringification happens first, so the following text never gets a chance to be expanded, thus you get stringified `"A"` as the final expansion of `A_STR`.

This problem is normally solved by introducing a second level of indirection, which gives the initial macro argument a second chance to expand:

```
#define QUOTE2(A) #A
#define QUOTE(A) QUOTE2(A)
```

However, this would not actually work for your case, because in the first-level expansion the `A` would expand to `0,0,0,1`, which would be taken as four arguments to `QUOTE2()`, and thus would be rejected as an invalid macro call.

You can solve this with variadic macro arguments and `__VA_ARGS__`:

```
#define QUOTE2(...) #__VA_ARGS__
#define QUOTE(...) QUOTE2(__VA_ARGS__)
```

Comment: It works! Special thanks for a great explanation of expansion process!